# Howto set the x-editable select with the value and see the text on click it?

Tags: jquery, html-select, x-editable

I have a select input with data loaded by ajax and the width div is small (only 2 characters).

I need set the select input (on success) with the value but show the text on click the select.

Situation: https://jsfiddle.net/9u7qm28h/

html:

```
<div id="my_id" style="margin: 50px">
  Select item: <a href="#" data-pk="1" data-value="1">1</a>
  Select item: <a href="#" data-pk="3" data-value="3">3</a>
</div>
```

my script:

```
$('#my_id a').editable({
  showbuttons: false,
  type: 'select',
  title: 'Select item',
  source: [
    {value: 1, text: 'this is the item #1'},
    {value: 2, text: 'this is the item #2'},
    {value: 3, text: 'this is the item #3'},
    {value: 4, text: 'this is the item #4'},
    {value: 5, text: 'this is the item #5'}
  ] });
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to set value?? on Div?

Comment: In the div or another container.
In the jsfindle link you see two editable elements. if you choose one and change it, the new editable is changed by 'this is the item #X'. I need that appear only the value but in the select It must appear like this now. Comment the line url: 'post.php' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use title attribute of anchor tag to add description for anchor tag. It will be displayed on hover.

Comment: It's not possible. When the "this is the item # 3" is selected will look on screen 3 ("this is the item #3" should not appear as now)